# why is the text written to my file perfectly fine until the last couple lines when its a loop in c?

Tags: c, macos, io, printf

I've been writing a small program in c and the file that is being created is correct until the last 150 lines or so where it starts getting random characters, sometimes with my program's filepath or part of it written in it.

note: I am using a mac retina and Xcode to write and test.

EDIT: unless you want to see the whole function I have put the part that is giving me trouble below this code

```
int vieditor()
{
    FILE *readtext, *writetext,*testfile,*writeagain;
    char mytest[1000][81],controller = '\0',worq;;
    int x,charactersperline = 0,lines = 0,i,k;



    /* this just creates a file with 1000 lines */
    testfile = fopen("/Users/scottcarlson/Classes/CS_222/test.txt","w");
    for (i = 0; i<1010; i = i+1)
    {
    fprintf(testfile,"this is line %d \n",i);
    }
    fclose(testfile);
    /* end of file creation */

    readtext = fopen("/Users/scottcarlson/Classes/CS_222/test.txt","r");
    writetext = fopen("/Users/scottcarlson/Classes/CS_222/test1.txt","w");

    if (!readtext)
    {
        printf ("test.txt does not exist");
    }
    else
    {
        while ( ( x = fgetc( readtext ) ) != EOF )
        {
            if (charactersperline < 80 && lines < 1000)
            {
                fprintf(writetext,"%c",x);
                char ch = x;
                mytest[lines][charactersperline] = ch;
                if (lines < 20)
                {
                    printf("%s",&mytest[lines][charactersperline]);
                }
            }

            if (x != 10)
            {
                charactersperline += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                charactersperline = 0;
                lines += 1;
            }

        }
        fclose(readtext);
        fclose(writetext);


    }
    do
    {
        fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        system("stty raw -echo");
        controller = getchar();
        system("stty cooked echo");
    }
    while (controller != 58);
    scanf("%s",&worq);
    if (worq == 'w')
    {
            writeagain = fopen("/Users/scottcarlson/Classes/CS_222/test.txt","w");
            for (k = 0; k<lines; k = k+1)
            {
                    fprintf(writeagain,"%s",mytest[k]);

            }

    }
    else if (strncmp(&worq,"q!",5))
    {
        return 0;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

That is the whole function, but you don't need to look at that unless you want to, the part that is causing me trouble is the bottom part right here

```
do
{
    fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
    system("stty raw -echo");
    controller = getchar();
    system("stty cooked echo");
}
while (controller != 58);
scanf("%s",&worq);
if (worq == 'w')
{
        writeagain = fopen("/Users/scottcarlson/Classes/CS_222/test.txt","w");
        for (k = 0; k<lines; k = k+1)
        {
                fprintf(writeagain,"%s",mytest[k]);

        }

}
else if (strncmp(&worq,"q!",5))
{
    return 0;
}


return 0
```

this is supposed to print (overwrite) a file test.txt, which it does perfectly fine up to about line 840, which as far as I can tell has no significance at all.

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated since I cannot find information on this anywhere else.

Here is the part of the file test.txt where it starts writing random things.

```
this is line 838 
this is line 839 
∆ø_ˇthis is line 840 
¿_ˇthis is line 841 
this is line 842 
ˇthis is line 843 
this is line 844 
this is line 845 
this is line 846 
this is line 847 
’ø_ˇthis is line 848 
–è7zthis is line 849 
_ˇthis is line 850 
ˇthis is line 851 
this is line 852 
this is line 853 
this is line 854 
Ä◊ø_ˇthis is line 855 
◊ø_ˇthis is line 856 
ïˇthis is line 857 
_ˇthis is line 858 
this is line 859 
this is line 860 
this is line 861 
this is line 862 
∞Ãø_ˇthis is line 863 
Ãø_ˇthis is line 864 
éìˇthis is line 865 
this is line 866 
ˇthis is line 867 
/lithis is line 868 
this is line 869 
this is line 870 
p¶√_ˇthis is line 871 
de/DerivedData/Project_5.c-akilnssybkcyvuetuwkrqlyxxtie/Build/Pthis is line 872 
ystem_pthread.dylibthis is line 872 
ystem_pthread.dylibthis is line 873 
this is line 874 
ˇthis is line 875 
this is line 876 
this is line 877 
this is line 878 
this is line 879 
.c-akilnssythis is line 880 
this is line 881 
_ˇthis is line 882
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not null-terminating your lines in mytest. fprintf expects to see a '\0' at the end of a string when printing using %s.

When you are copying character by character into mytest, you either need to put code in to add the '\0' at the end of each line or you could initialize the whole array to '\0's at the start.
The simplest (but not most efficient) way is to add the '\0' after each time you add a character.

```
mytest[lines][charactersperline] = ch;
mytest[lines][charactersperline+1] = '\0';
```

You also have to add a zero-byte at the start of the line when you start a new line, as your loop may not continue around to put anything into that line.

Note that you also have an issue if you don't have anything in your file, or if your file doesn't end with '\n' as you won't increase the line count *lines*

Also

```
printf("%s",&mytest[lines][charactersperline]);
```

should be %c not %s as you are printing a single character.

Comment: It worked! thank you so much.  if it's not too much trouble could you or someone explain why the program was putting parts of different files paths in my printed text file?  I get that it needs the '\0' at the end now, but I don't understand why it would be causing those types of errors exactly.  Thanks again you're a lifesaver!

Comment: The memory that mytest is using is not initialized, that means it has whatever random stuff that happened to be in that memory to start with. Without the '\0' at the end of the string the printf will keep printing all the extra stuff until it hits another '\0' byte. The file paths that were printed were probably used by another part of the program (e.g. the runtime library start up) and the memory was given back to the program to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s",&worq);
```

It looks like `worq` is a `char`. The `"%s"` conversion specifier will match a string and write all the characters in the string at the address provided (that of a single char).

I suspect you have a buffer overflow issue (even if only 1 char is read, `scanf` will write the terminating zero-byte at an invalid location).

You can read a single character with the `%c` conversion specifier.

Comment: I changed this, the post above solved most of the issue but I was still getting an odd readout at the end of my file after it should have stopped printing and this fixed it!